# Did Mary, the mother of Jesus, play a role in prompting or encouraging him to initiate the signs of his ministry?

Tags: jesus

John 2:1-5 English Standard Version

> On the third day there was a wedding at Cana in Galilee, and the
> mother of Jesus was there. Jesus also was invited to the wedding with
> his disciples. When the wine ran out, the mother of Jesus said to him,
> “They have no wine.” And Jesus said to her, “Woman, what does this
> have to do with me? My hour has not yet come.” His mother said to the
> servants, “Do whatever he tells you.”

Did Mary, the mother of Jesus, play a role in prompting or encouraging him to initiate the signs of his ministry?

Comment: We are not told so we do not know.

Comment: "This is how Jesus began his signs in Cana in Galilee..." John 2:11  What does "began" mean in this context?

Comment: "Began" is simply that this was the first miracle Jesus performed as the narrative tells us.

Comment: The phrase "My hour has not yet come." Does this mean that Jesus was not at the time of performing miraculous signs, he only did so through the intervention of Mary?

Comment: "My hour is not yet come" was the point at which the Messiah openly revealed Himself.  Despite the miracle, this was not done at the wedding (all were asked to leave while the miracle occurred) but later at the first sermon at Cana.  This should be the subject of the question.

Comment: I have asked a Question on whether some narrative is missing between the last two verses. Jesus plainly refuses to intervene, but Mary gives directions to the servants to do what Jesus asks for! Why was she sure that Jesus would oblige her ? After all, she was his mother and had seen him grow up . She knew he would never say a final no to her. Call it intervention, prompting or encouraging - the miracle was there to happen !

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/99392/are-there-any-apocryphal-writings-on-the-apparent-gap-between-verses-4-and-5-of

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/99390/was-the-host-of-wedding-feast-at-cana-a-close-relative-or-friend-of-mother-mary

Answer (score 0):

Mary is not just prompting, but almost 'pushing'Jesus into performing the miracle. Jesus first refuses to intervene, saying that shortage of wine is none of their business. He may not have been happy with the wedding-host shying away from speaking to the Host of Heavenly Banquet, about the unfortunate event. After his ney saying, Mary does not plead with Jesus again. In stead, she asks the servants to ' do what he asks of them'.  She must have said that right in front of Jesus. He must have given her a smile saying " Mom, you never gave me a chance .." After all, she is his mother; how can he say a final no to her, even if heavens were not going to fall if he did not do a miracle ?